# Measuring person's height using Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect, euclidean-distance

I am trying to calculate the height of a person using Kinect. Here is how I calculate the height (this code is not very sophisticated, it is only for testing purposes):

```
double h2s =  Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(headX - shoulderCenterX, 2) + Math.Pow(headY - shoulderCenterY, 2)+ Math.Pow(headZ - shoulderCenterZ, 2));
double s2hip =  Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(shoulderCenterX - hipX, 2) + Math.Pow(shoulderCenterY - hipY, 2) + Math.Pow(shoulderCenterZ - hipZ, 2));
double hip2Lhip =  Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(hipX - hipLeftX, 2) + Math.Pow(hipY - hipLeftY, 2) + Math.Pow(hipZ - hipLeftZ, 2));
double Lhip2kneeL =  Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(hipLeftX - kneeLeftX, 2) + Math.Pow(hipLeftY - kneeLeftY, 2) + Math.Pow(hipLeftZ - kneeLeftZ, 2));
double kneeL2ankle = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(kneeLeftX - ankleLeftX, 2) + Math.Pow(kneeLeftY - ankleLeftY, 2) + Math.Pow(kneeLeftZ - ankleLeftZ, 2));

double heigth = h2s + s2hip + hip2Lhip + Lhip2kneeL + kneeL2ankle;

vyskatextbox.Text = heigth.ToString();
```

I am not getting any error, but the thing is that it is calculating my height wrong. I am getting numbers between 3 to 11 depending on how close I was to Kinect. What could be wrong? Is it all right that the number changes or should it stay the same no matter what? Also why do I get numbers like 11 (m)?

Comment: And what units are your various coordinates (headX etc) in...?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I am not converting anything, this is straight from kinect, for example: headX = head.Position.X;   So I guess it should be in meters.

Comment: So you're guessing and not sure? Did you even read the documentation?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I have red documentation and topics on other forums and even scientific articles from datbases like "SCOPUS" and "Web of Science". Still I am not sure, because I do not think I could be 11m tall you know :) It would be very kind of you if you could give me explanation on why do I get such wierd values. Thank you

Comment: Just why are you people voting my question down? If the answer is so childish and obvious to you, please do not be selfish and share it with other people, who might not be that experienced as you are. If this is not the case why do you vote my question down, then please leave a comment and I will try to improve this and future questions. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I see a `shoulderCenter` in your code, so you are probably using the Microsoft Kinect SDK v1.x. In this case, the skeletal joints are the following ones:

[image: Kinect SDK v1.x Skeletal Joints]

### Height estimation in Microsoft Kinect SDK v1.x

Assume that we have a function that can calculate the distance between two joints. We name this function `d(joint1, joint2)`.

Assume also that we have defined a function which can calculate the average point between two joints (note that the following is just pseudocode):

```
function avg(joint1, joint2) {
    avg_joint.x = (joint1.x + joint2.x) / 2.0;
    avg_joint.y = (joint1.y + joint2.y) / 2.0;
    avg_joint.z = (joint1.z + joint2.z) / 2.0;
    return avg_joint;
}
```

A good algorithm to estimate the user's height can be the following one (note that it is just a pseudocode):

```
torso_height = d(HEAD, SHOULDER_CENTER) +
               d(SHOULDER_CENTER, SPINE) +
               d(SPINE, HIP_CENTER) +
               d(HIP_CENTER, avg(HIP_RIGHT, HIP_LEFT));

left_leg_height = d(HIP_LEFT, KNEE_LEFT) +
                  d(KNEE_LEFT, ANKLE_LEFT) +
                  d(ANKLE_LEFT, FOOT_LEFT);

right_leg_height = d(HIP_RIGHT, KNEE_RIGHT) +
                   d(KNEE_RIGHT, ANKLE_RIGHT) +
                   d(ANKLE_RIGHT, FOOT_RIGHT);

tot_height = torso_height +
             (left_leg_height + right_leg_height) / 2.0;
```

**If all joints are well tracked**, this algorithm works pretty well. However, it is possible (and it actually happens quite often) that some joints are **inferred**. In [this page from the documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131025.aspx), you can see how to test if joints are inferred in C#.

If a joint is inferred, the possibilities that its position is wrong increase. And so the possibilities that height estimation will fail increases too.

The following method can be used to test if all joints are well tracked. It returns `false` if at least one joint is not well tracked; otherwise it returns `true`:

```
function areJointsWellTracked(JointCollection joints)
{
    foreach (Joint joint in joints)
        if(joint.TrackingState != JointTrackingState.Tracked)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

So what you can do to improve user's height estimation is to calculate it ONLY when all joints are well tracked.

Moreover, consider the possibility to provide always the average of more than one of the last height values. For instance, you can memorize the last ten height values in an array, and then provide everytime the average of these values. This will help to reduce the effect of noise in your measures.

### Your problem

Your code seems to be a simplified version of the algorithm that I have just described. So the only reason why you can get those strange values are that tracking is not working well. My suggestion is to try to use the aforementioned `areJointsWellTracked` method, and estimate the height only when all joints are well tracked.

### Additional note for Microsoft Kinect SDK v2

For developers that are using SDK v2, note that skeletal joints are not defined as in SDK v1.x. The following image shows this difference:

[image: Kinect SDK v2 Skeletal Joints]

Due to the different positions and definitions of some joints, the above algorithm to evaluate the height should be edited as follows:

```
torso_height = d(HEAD, NECK)+
               d(NECK, SPINE_SHOULDER) +
               d(SPINE_SHOULDER, SPINE_MID) +
               d(SPINE_MID, SPINE_BASE) +
               d(SPINE_BASE, avg(HIP_RIGHT, HIP_LEFT));

left_leg_height = d(HIP_LEFT, KNEE_LEFT) +
                  d(KNEE_LEFT, ANKLE_LEFT) +
                  d(ANKLE_LEFT, FOOT_LEFT);

right_leg_height = d(HIP_RIGHT, KNEE_RIGHT) +
                   d(KNEE_RIGHT, ANKLE_RIGHT) +
                   d(ANKLE_RIGHT, FOOT_RIGHT);

tot_height = torso_height +
             (left_leg_height + right_leg_height) / 2.0;
```

You can find an interesting discussion on how to evaluate user's height with Microsoft Kinect SDK v2 at [this link](http://pterneas.com/2012/06/08/kinect-for-windows-find-user-height-accurately/).

Comment: how can we find the body distance from Kinect 2.0 /specially When Kinect is not straight to our face but it makes an  angle

Answer (score 1):

this link was helpful to me.
[Find user height accurately](http://pterneas.com/2012/06/08/kinect-for-windows-find-user-height-accurately/)